# Using a specific seed in the `RANDOM_NUMBER` algorithm

Tags: random, fortran, random-seed

I'm looking to use a specific set of seeds for the intrinsic function `RANDOM_NUMBER` (a PRNG). What I've read so far is that the seed value can be set via calling `RANDOM_SEED`, specifically `RANDOM_SEED(GET = array)`. My confusion is how to (if it's possible) set a specific value for the algorithm, for instance in the `RAND`, `RANDU`, or `RANDM` algorithms one can specify their own seed directly. I'm not sure how to set the seed, as the get function seems to take an array. If it takes an array, does it always pull the seed value from a specific index in the array? 
Basically, is there a way to set a specific single seed value? If so, would someone be able to write-it out?

As a side note - I'm attempting to set my seed because allegedly one of the other PRNGs I mentioned only works well with "large odd numbers" according to my professor, so I decided that I may as well control this when comparing the PRNG's.

Comment: Use tag fortran for all.Fortran questions. You can add a version tag for version specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `RANDOM_SEED` is only used for controlimg the seed of `RANDOM_NUMBER()`. If you use any other random number generator subroutine or function, it will not affect them at all or if yes then in some compiler specific way which you must find in the manual. But most probably it does not affect them.

Second, you should not care at all whether the seed array contains 1, 4 or 42 integers, it doesn't matter because the PRNG uses the bits from the whole array in some unspecified custom way. For example you may be generating 64 bit real numbers, but the seed array is made of 32 bit integers. You cannot simply say which integer from the seed array does what. **You can view the whole seed array as one big integer number that is cut into smaller pieces if you want.**

Regarding your professors advice, who knows what he meant, but the seed is probably set by some procedure of that particular generator, and not by the standard `RANDOM_SEED`, so you must read the documentation for that generator.

And how to use a specific seed in `RANDOM_SEED`? It was described on this site several times,jkust search for `RANDOM_SEED` in the top right search field, really. But it is simple, once you know the size of the array, size it to any non-trivial numbers (you need enough non-zero bits) you want and use `put=`. That's really all, just **don't think about individual values** in the array, the whole array is **one piece of data** together.